# Variable not getting passed to Pug

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I am creating an express.js app as part of a team project. I'm a javascipt novice, but the task ultimately fell to me. The purpose of the relevant code is to run a script when a button is clicked, using some user-defined options, then show a new page and display links for the reports that have been generated on a results page. For whatever reason, this never works the first time after the app is started, but it will work if you go back and try again. I had thought there was a synchronization issue, and there might be, but there also seems to be an issue with the array variables not being passed to pug. I've been slamming my head against the desk to this for weeks, and asked for assistance from my professor (neither of us are CS people) with no luck. Please help.

Here's the app variables, configuration, etc. at the beginning of the file:

```
// index.js

/**
 * Required External Modules
 */

const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const shell = require("shelljs");
const fs = require("fs");






/**
 * App Variables
 */

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || "8000";
var ipAddresses;
var ipAddressesLink;








/**
 *  App Configuration
 */

app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.set("view engine", "pug");
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "reports/html")));

//code to make html forms work
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Here's the relevant route that keeps failing me:

```
//Run script when post is rec'd from root and send to results page
app.post("/", (req, res) => {
    //take values and create complete command for Astrum script
    var commandString = 'bash /home/astrum/Main/Astrum.sh -s ' + req.body.speed + ' -h ' + req.body.host + ' -u ' + req.body.username + ' -p ' + req.body.password;
    var pathToReports = './reports/html';
  
    runScript(commandString);

    readFolder(pathToReports);
    
    renderPage();
    
    
    //Iterate thru filenames to create arrays for links and link labels
    function readFolder(pathValue) {

        fs.readdir(pathValue, (err, files) => {

            console.log(files)
                
            //variable & method for links to html records pages
            ipAddressesLink = files;

            console.log(ipAddressesLink);
            
            //variable and method to remove file extension for link labels in pug
            ipAddresses = files.map(removeExtension);

            
        });

    }

    //function to remove last five characters of each element
    function removeExtension(value) {

        return value.substring(0, value.length - 5);

    };

    //function to render the page
    function renderPage() {

        res.render("results", {ipAddressesLink, ipAddresses, title: 'Results'});

    }

    //function to execute command in shell
    function runScript(value) {

        shell.exec(value);

    }


    //show array on console for debugging
    console.log("type of record is: " + typeof ipAddressesLink);
    console.log(ipAddressesLink);
    console.log(ipAddresses);

    res.end();
});
```

Here is the pug template for the results page which is throwing the error, obviously a work in progress:

```
extends layout

block layout-content
  
  div.View
    
    div.Message
      
      div.Title
        
        h1 Astrum Network Analysis
      
        div.Body          
          
          div.multiple-group
          
            h3 Heading
            select(id='whitelist', name='whitelist' size='6' multiple)
              option(value="volvo") Volvo
              option(value="saab") Saab
              option(value="fiat") Fiat
              option(value="audi") Audi
              option(value="bmw") BMW


          div.form-group

            label(for='whitelistButton')
            input(type='submit' value='Whitelist Ports')


          h3 Hosts Found:  
            
            ul

              each val, index in ipAddressesLink

                li: a( href = val ) #{ipAddresses[index]}
```

And here's the error message I get:

```
TypeError: /home/astrum/Main/astrumApp/views/results.pug:36
    34|             ul
    35| 
  > 36|               each val, index in ipAddressesLink
    37| 
    38|                 li: a( href = val ) #{ipAddresses[index]}
    39| 

Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at eval (eval at wrap (/home/astrum/Main/astrumApp/node_modules/pug-runtime/wrap.js:6:10), <anonymous>:93:32)
    at eval (eval at wrap (/home/astrum/Main/astrumApp/node_modules/pug-runtime/wrap.js:6:10), <anonymous>:116:4)
    at template (eval at wrap (/home/astrum/Main/astrumApp/node_modules/pug-runtime/wrap.js:6:10), <anonymous>:119:7)
    at Object.exports.renderFile (/home/astrum/Main/astrumApp/node_modules/pug/lib/index.js:452:38)
    at Object.exports.renderFile (/home/astrum/Main/astrumApp/node_modules/pug/lib/index.js:442:21)
    at View.exports.__express [as engine] (/home/astrum/Main/astrumApp/node_modules/pug/lib/index.js:491:11)
    at View.render (/home/astrum/Main/astrumApp/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (/home/astrum/Main/astrumApp/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (/home/astrum/Main/astrumApp/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (/home/astrum/Main/astrumApp/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1012:7)
```

Comment: You sure files aren't empty? What does the `console.log(ipAddressesLink)` print out though?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `fs.readdirSync`! I'm sure `fs.readdir` in `readFolder` function is running out of your expected process order:

```
function readFolder(pathValue) {

    //variable & method for links to html records pages
    ipAddressesLink = fs.readdirSync(pathValue);

    //variable and method to remove file extension for link labels in pug
    ipAddresses = ipAddressesLink.map(removeExtension);

}
```

Comment: Nailed it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
 //function to render the page
function renderPage() {

    res.render("results", {ipAddressesLink, ipAddresses, title: 'Results'});

}
```

to:

```
 //function to render the page
function renderPage() {

    res.render("results", {ipAddressesLink: ipAddressesLink, ipAddresses: ipAddresses, title: 'Results'});

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work, but thanks for your help.